# Issue with printing lists which automatically number themselves based on amount of list entries

Tags: python, list

So, I try to print all the entries in list "options" numbered. I want to automate the number prefix, so I use the con variable. Why is this not working? I get the following string printed, which is just the range argument I use in the "For" line:

> 0 \n 1 \n 2

(The **\n**s are not literally printed, I just used them to signify newlines)

```
options = ["Option A", "Option B", "Option C"]
noptions = len(options)
con = 1
for options in range(0, int(noptions)):
      print(*str(options), sep = "\n[" + str(con) + "] - ")
      con += 1
```

Any help?

Comment: use `enumerate`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` for that like,

```
>>> options = ["Option A", "Option B", "Option C"]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for idx, option in enumerate(options):
...   print(f"{idx} - {option}") # if python < 3.6 then use `str.format` instead of `f-strings`
... 
0 - Option A
1 - Option B
2 - Option C
>>>
```

if you want to start from any other index than `0`, then use pass `start` index to `enumerate` like,

> enumerate(iterable[, start]) -> iterator for index, value of iterable

```
>>> for idx, option in enumerate(options, 1):
...   print(f"{idx} - {option}")
... 
1 - Option A
2 - Option B
3 - Option C
```

Comment: And if I want them to be listed starting from 1 rather than 0?

Comment: `enumerate` can take `start` index too

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate`

```py
options = ["Option A", "Option B", "Option C"]

for i, option in enumerate(options):
    print(i,' ',option)
```

**Output:**

```py
0   Option A
1   Option B
2   Option C
```

You can also give a starting value of the index using the `start` option

```py
options = ["Option A", "Option B", "Option C"]

for i, option in enumerate(options, start=1):
    print(i,' ',option)
```

**Output:**

```py
1   Option A
2   Option B
3   Option C
```